# Is there a good tool for debugging XAML's databinding behavior / errors at runtime?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

WPF is a great toolset, and XAML databinding is very powerful, but I've often run into difficulty arising from its transparency: It can be tough to debug a databinding failure when no errors are thrown.

For example, I recently had to change a `Style` declaration like this:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TestProperty}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="DataGridRow.Background" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Into this:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.TestProperty}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="DataGridRow.Background" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

In order for the DataGridRow property to be affected. It would be incredibly helpful to see, at design- or run-time, what the implications of binding to different sources and `RelativeSource`s would be.

Do any such tools / techniques exist?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [`PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.presentationtracesources.tracelevel.aspx) attached property on bindings to get detailed logging in the output during runtime.

In your case, it will look like this:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="False" Binding="{Binding DataContext.TestProperty,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},
                    PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}">
                <Setter Property="DataGridRow.Background" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: This definitely helped - accepted! For completeness, since inspecting the visual tree at runtime is a related concern, I'd also like to point out [Snoop](http://www.blois.us/Snoop/) to anyone who remains unaware of its charms.

Comment: The most recent version of Snoop can be found on CodePlex: http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Helpful for me was the correct Tracelevel on the output window. Options > Debugging > Output Window > Data Binding. As descript here: http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2010/06/24/visual-studio-2010-wpf-trace-settings-default-is-incorrect

Comment: Snoop moved to github: https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf

Answer (score 4):

Bea Stollnitz has a very informative blog post about [debugging WPF bindings](https://web.archive.org/web/20091011164507/http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=52).

If you are using Visual Studio 2010, you will need to [update the default WPF trace setting](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2010/06/24/visual-studio-2010-wpf-trace-settings-default-is-incorrect/).

Comment: +1 Thanks very much for pointing out the need to update the VS2010 setting; I would've burned a lot of time on that one.

Answer (score 3):

If you run your application under the Visual Studio debugger, binding errors will be reported to the output window.  These are very informative and should help you track down any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Another option in Visual Studio 2010 is to put a breakpoint on the binding. This can easily be done by putting your clicking on the Binding keyword and pressing F9 to set the breakpoint. The Binding keyword will be highlighted in red. If a larger chunk of text is highlighted, it may be that the breakpoint does not work in the editor that you are using. If this happens, try right-clicking the file in Solution Explorer, select "Open with" and choose "Source Code (Text) Editor".

When you hit the breakpoint at runtime, you can examine it using the Locals debugger window and see what it is bound to.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Visual Studio 2010: when viewing a XAML file, no breakpoint options appear in the Debug menu, and pressing F9 with the cursor on `{Binding ...` has no effect. Can you clarify what you're doing (perhaps with a screenshot) to achieve this?