# Reusing WPF layout XAML with Bindings?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've been stuck on trying to reuse layout code for my WPF application.

I'm trying to make an XML editor that lets you have multiple files open (via tabs).

My situation is as follows:

```
<TabControl>
  <TabItem>
    // Layout XAML with various {Binding} sources (File 1)
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem>
    // Layout XAML with various {Binding} sources (File 2)
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem>
    // Layout XAML with various {Binding} sources (File 3)
  </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

This works; however, each of the three **TabItems** is a huge chunk of copy & pasted code, with only a few names changed to avoid duplicate names.

I want to rewrite the code in such a way that something like this is possible:

```
<TabControl>
  <TabItem>
    // Reference to Template
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem>
    // Reference to Template
   </TabItem>
  <TabItem>
    // Reference to Template
  </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

And have a **Template** defined somewhere else.

I tried using a **DataTemplate** for the template, and assigning it to each **TabItem** with **ContentTemplate**, but although the layout displayed properly, all of the **{Bindings}** were lost.

I've googled extensively, but haven't been able to figure out how I should be approaching this.

I would greatly appreciate any links to demos that would show how to achieve binding without copy & pasting code.

I would also appreciate any tips for debugging failed bindings, other than trying things out until they work. (I'm comfortable debugging C# with the debugger, but not sure how to inspect XAML stuff)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean, the bindings were lost? Data templating something won't remove binding strings (see every usage of one as an `ItemTemplate`)

Comment: I have an XmlDataProvider outside the TabControl. Within the TabControl, I have things like ItemsSource="{Binding}. When I run the program, the data doesn't show up on the screen if I use the template.

Comment: @Brent you'd better be wrapping the tab behavior in its own view model then.

Comment: @Brent [Debugging XAML bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4026641/293099).

Comment: As the other commenters have said, I would fix it so that a DataTemplate *will* work (as it should).

Comment: @Athari: Thanks for the debugging tip!! :)

Comment: @Crono: do you have a tutorial for this? Thanks!

Comment: re: tips for debugging: look in the `Output` window for failed bindings -- it will tell you from what context an object is trying to get a property.

Comment: Is this something easily fixed by just specifying your DataContext on your DataTemplate, or am I missing something?

Comment: Sometimes when I can't figure out what's wrong with a binding, I put in something like this: whatever = {Binding XXXX}, and then you can usually spot the XXXX text (yes, actually 4 X's) in the output. You'll get a message saying that XXXX is not a member of some object, and then suddenly it's: 'Oh yeah, that's not what I wanted to bind to!"

Comment: Great suggestions! I was able to figure out the problem :D

Answer (score 0):

You should represent your tab items with an ObservableCollection, using the Window's ViewModel.

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TabItems, Mode=OneTime}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedTab, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border Name="Border" Margin="0,0,-4,0" BorderThickness="1">
                                <ContentPresenter
                                    x:Name="ContentSite"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    Margin="12,2,12,2"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    ContentSource="Header"
                                    RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        etc...

                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        etc...

                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

Each tab item would then be a view model itself, with all the data inside that you need to bind to for each tab. So for example:

```
public ObservableCollection<TabItemViewModel> TabItems
{
    get
    {
        return m_SuspendTabItems;
    }
    private set
    {
        if (Equals(m_SuspendTabItems, value))
        {
            return;
        }

        m_SuspendTabItems = value;

        NotifyPropertyChanged(s_SuspendTabItems);
    }
}
```

Would be on your main WindowViewModel. To add a new tab, you would simply call TabItems.Add(new TabItemViewmodel());.

Where "TabItemViewModel" contains your binding for that particular tab item.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write a custom UserControl containing everything you now are copy-pasting, and add this UserControl into the tab items. Add to this UserControl your required sources as a Dependency Property. Now you can access it from your TabControl without loosing Bindings.

I made a quick non-working example:

MyControl.xaml

```
<UserControl Name=this>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text={Binding Something, ElementName=this} />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

MyControl.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomethingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Something", typeof(string), typeof(MyControl));

    public string KeyType
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SomethingProperty ); }
        set { SetValue(SomethingProperty , value); }
    }
}
```

program.xaml

```
<Window>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem>
            <MyControl Something={Binding Anything[0] />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem>
            <MyControl Something={Binding Anything[1] />
        </TabItem>
        //...
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

program.xaml.cs

```
//...
public string[] Anything { get; set; }
//...
```

Be aware that this is only a very simple example. You could easily add your required model as mentioned above to an ObservableCollection and generate the tab items from that automatically.