# bind itemcount to datacontext

Tags: c#, xaml

how do i binding itemcount to my datacontext to count all the items in each of my groups and then show it in the header

Mærke is the `PropertyGroupDescription` where my items are binding to

view model

```
string Data = 
    @"Select ps.Mærket AS Mærke, P.DataID, P.Billed, P.Model, 
          P.Årgang, P.[Motor Type], P.Krydsmål, P.Centerhul, 
          P.ET,P.Bolter, P.Dæk, P.Fælge ,PS.Krydsmålene
      from Data.Hjuldata P  
      inner join Data.Mærke PS on P.MærkeID = PS.MærkeID 
      ORDER BY ps.Mærket";

ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(hjuldata.ItemsSource);
dataView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Mærke"));
```

data context

```
<Expander.Header>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{Binding Items}">
        <Image Source="{Binding Billed}" Width="20" Height="20" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mærke}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFEAEAEA" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Krydsmålene}"  FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFFBFB00" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,150,0" TextAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
</Expander.Header>
```

it worked before with this

```
<Expander.Header>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFEAEAEA" FontSize="22 "VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>                                          
    </StackPanel>
</Expander.Header>
```

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference
>   'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl', AncestorLevel='1''.
>   BindingExpression:Path=ItemCount; DataItem=null;
>   target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Comment: Without knowing what your DataContext is, that is kind of hard to guess. Maybe if you would post your ViewModel we can help.

Comment: i had updatet it now with that

Comment: hard to guess, but shooting blind: try DataContext = this;

Comment: Is ItemCount the only binding not working ? Is the other Billed, Maerke binding working ? To more easily debug the binding, you can check the debugger output window. There is also a lot of details here about how to find the root cause of the binding issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026543/is-there-a-good-tool-for-debugging-xamls-databinding-behavior-errors-at-runti

Comment: yes all the others are working fine except itemCount

Comment: Is there any binding related message in the output window of the debugger ? It could be because there is a typo on your property name, or your property is always null and/or the PropertyChanged event is never raised with the not null value ?

Comment: i dont get anything by doing this <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},
                    PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}
not sure if it is because is not called since itemcount is not something that are in the cs

Comment: Can you share the code of your Items view model ? I'm not sure to get what you mean by "itemcount is not something that are in the cs".

Comment: i found the error after digging abit deeper in it 
but here you can see http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/ what i mean with itemcount is not in the cs(just scroll down to the buttom)

Comment: Please post a [Short Self Contained Compilable Example](http://sscce.org/). Your code listings are missing so much that it is impossible to see what you are trying to do (we can't psychically work out your class structure).

Comment: missing? the other things that are more in my code other than that i had alredy postet is the design and SQL connection which are working fine and dont have anything to do with this so i dont see a need for that as is just the binding that are problems with

Comment: @Aron don't you see that he is trying to do a counting on his items and make it to be showed in the header 
BTW i am trying to do something similar to my datagrid but it seems like itemcount is only a property for Name so i guess you have to create something like a class for that

Comment: @KewinBjörkNielsen I can see exactly what he WANTS to do. I cannot see how he is trying to achieve it. It is obvious that he has something he expects to work. I can also very easily write something else that DOES work in about 10 minutes (far less time than I have already spent here). What I CAN'T do is fix his code when 90% of it is missing. I don't expect to have my vet replace my cat everytime I go in to see him about a cough.

Answer (score 1):

this here should work

```
<TextBlock FontSize="22" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
<Run Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=Items.Count, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: that got me one step closer now it shows all my items that are in the whole listview on all the headers instead of the grouped items